# How to access auth_user_group table by ID

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-3, django-4.0

How can I directly specify the ID column of `auth_user_group` table in queries/DML?

I am referring to `auth_user_group.id`, **not** `auth_group.id` nor `auth_user_group.group_id`.

For example, I want to directly issue DML like:

```
delete from auth_user_group where auth_user_group.id = 1

select id, user_id, group_id from auth_user_group where auth_user_group.id = 1;
```

I am **not** interested in the following workaround which avoids `auth_user_group` by requiring knowledge of the group name, instead of the `auth_user_group.id`, and results in two queries instead of 1:

```
group = Groups.get(name='foo')
user.groups.remove(group)
```

If you wanted to directly query a junction/M:N table in Django, normally you would create a "through Model" and can then query it directly. However in this case, the django.contrib.auth.models definition do not use a through model. I'm willing to create a custom AbstractUser where groups is defined as a through table if that would work. But I'm not sure how to specify the through table since `auth_user_group` does not have its own model in django.contrib.auth.models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no explicit through model, you can access the implicit `through` model

`Group.user_set.through.objects.get(id=1)`

or

`User.groups.through.objects.get(id=1)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. Where did you learn that? Just from browsing the docs?

Comment: Reading docs, diving into source code, been using Django for many years now...